# Azure Devops Repo branches

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc, azure-repos

On my Azure DevOps I cannot see branches. How can I enable branches?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose TFVC(Team Foundation Version control) as version control when you create a new project, the default repo will have no Branches page.
[image]

So, you can choose git as version control when you create new projects or create a new repo in this project. A project can only have one TFVC repository but can have multiple git repositories.
[image]

You can refer to the documents and learn more about [Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/?view=azure-devops) and [TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/?view=azure-devops) in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **TFVC** you can't see the branches in the menu, you will see them under the "Files":

[image]

Only if you use **Git** you will see the Branches in the menu:

[image]